# Replacing all elements in a nested Array

Tags: javascript

I have a challenge that I have been battling with for some time now.  It's about replacing all the elements in an array that is in a grid form, but my solution is only replacing selected element of its choice not as I intended.

In this challenge, I want to replace the integer value that is divisible by two with the string "even" while the rest replaced with the string "odd".

/*
 *   - The `numbers` variable is an array of arrays.
 *   - a nested `for` loop to cycle through `numbers`.
 *   - it convert each even number to the string "even"
 *   - and Convert each odd number to the string "odd"
 */

```
var myNumbers = [
    [243, 12, 23, 12, 45, 45, 78, 66, 223, 3],
    [34, 2, 1, 553, 23, 4, 66, 23, 4, 55],
    [67, 56, 45, 553, 44, 55, 5, 428, 452, 3],
    [12, 31, 55, 445, 79, 44, 674, 224, 4, 21],
    [4, 2, 3, 52, 13, 51, 44, 1, 67, 5],
    [5, 65, 4, 5, 5, 6, 5, 43, 23, 4424],
    [74, 532, 6, 7, 35, 17, 89, 43, 43, 66],
    [53, 6, 89, 10, 23, 52, 111, 44, 109, 80],
    [67, 6, 53, 537, 2, 168, 16, 2, 1, 8],
    [76, 7, 9, 6, 3, 73, 77, 100, 56, 100]
];

for(var row=0; row<myNumbers.length; row++) {
    for(var column=0;column<myNumbers[row].length;column++) {
        if(myNumbers[column]%2===0){
            myNumbers[column].splice(column,1,"even");
        }else{ 
            myNumbers[column].splice(column,1,"odd");
        }
        console.log(myNumbers[row][column]);
     }
}
```

Code Output:
  
odd
12
23
12
45
45
78
66
223
3
34
odd
1
553
23
4
66
23
4
55
67
56
odd
553
44
55
5
428
452
3
12
31
55
odd
79
44
674
224
4
21
4
2
3
52
odd
51
44
1
67
5
5
65
4
5
5
odd
5
43
23
4424
74
532
6
7
35
17
odd
43
43
66
53
6
89
10
23
52
111
odd
109
80
67
6
53
537
2
168
16
2
odd
8
76
7
9
6
3
73
77
100
56
odd

Answer (score 2):

Probably easier to use a nested `map` instead:

```js
var myNumbers = [
    [243, 12, 23, 12, 45, 45, 78, 66, 223, 3],
    [34, 2, 1, 553, 23, 4, 66, 23, 4, 55],
    [67, 56, 45, 553, 44, 55, 5, 428, 452, 3],
    [12, 31, 55, 445, 79, 44, 674, 224, 4, 21],
    [4, 2, 3, 52, 13, 51, 44, 1, 67, 5],
    [5, 65, 4, 5, 5, 6, 5, 43, 23, 4424],
    [74, 532, 6, 7, 35, 17, 89, 43, 43, 66],
    [53, 6, 89, 10, 23, 52, 111, 44, 109, 80],
    [67, 6, 53, 537, 2, 168, 16, 2, 1, 8],
    [76, 7, 9, 6, 3, 73, 77, 100, 56, 100]
];
const output = myNumbers.map(row => row.map(num =>
  num % 2 === 0
  ? 'even'
  : 'odd'
));
console.log(output);
```

Achieving the same thing with a `for` loop is *much* more verbose and confusing, and shouldn't be done in most cases (array methods have better abstraction and don't require manual iteration), but if necessary:

```js
var myNumbers = [
    [243, 12, 23, 12, 45, 45, 78, 66, 223, 3],
    [34, 2, 1, 553, 23, 4, 66, 23, 4, 55],
    [67, 56, 45, 553, 44, 55, 5, 428, 452, 3],
    [12, 31, 55, 445, 79, 44, 674, 224, 4, 21],
    [4, 2, 3, 52, 13, 51, 44, 1, 67, 5],
    [5, 65, 4, 5, 5, 6, 5, 43, 23, 4424],
    [74, 532, 6, 7, 35, 17, 89, 43, 43, 66],
    [53, 6, 89, 10, 23, 52, 111, 44, 109, 80],
    [67, 6, 53, 537, 2, 168, 16, 2, 1, 8],
    [76, 7, 9, 6, 3, 73, 77, 100, 56, 100]
];
const output = [];
for (let rowIndex = 0; rowIndex < myNumbers.length; rowIndex++) {
  const row = myNumbers[rowIndex];
  const newRow = [];
  for (let colIndex = 0; colIndex < row.length; colIndex++) {
    const num = row[colIndex];
    newRow.push(num % 2 === 0 ? 'even' : 'odd');
  }
  output.push(newRow);
}

console.log(output);
```

Comment: i'm confused to why this is working, shouldn't there be a return statement ?

Comment: Wow, but this seems too advanced to grasp.  Please come down to my level. Can you break it down first using my beloved nested for, thereafter this advanced method...

Comment: @ZohirSalakCeNa Arrow functions without `{` blocks have implicit return.

Comment: Oh i see now, i still only use `function(){}`, Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

You used the wrong variable for the row index

```
myNumbers[column]
//needs to be
myNumbers[row]
```

Also your if condition is using the wrong row index, and trying to compare against the whole array instead of the value in the array

```
if(myNumbers[column]%2===0)
//needs to be
if(myNumbers[row][column]%2===0)
```

Demo

```js
var myNumbers = [
  [243, 12, 23, 12, 45, 45, 78, 66, 223, 3],
  [34, 2, 1, 553, 23, 4, 66, 23, 4, 55],
  [67, 56, 45, 553, 44, 55, 5, 428, 452, 3],
  [12, 31, 55, 445, 79, 44, 674, 224, 4, 21],
  [4, 2, 3, 52, 13, 51, 44, 1, 67, 5],
  [5, 65, 4, 5, 5, 6, 5, 43, 23, 4424],
  [74, 532, 6, 7, 35, 17, 89, 43, 43, 66],
  [53, 6, 89, 10, 23, 52, 111, 44, 109, 80],
  [67, 6, 53, 537, 2, 168, 16, 2, 1, 8],
  [76, 7, 9, 6, 3, 73, 77, 100, 56, 100]
];

for (var row = 0; row < myNumbers.length; row++) {
  for (var column = 0; column < myNumbers[row].length; column++) {
    if (myNumbers[row][column] % 2 === 0) {
      myNumbers[row].splice(column, 1, "even");
    } else {
      myNumbers[row].splice(column, 1, "odd");
    }
  }
}
console.log(myNumbers);
```

Comment: I agree with you completely. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Why not simply set the value of `myNumbers[row][column]` instead of using `splice`?

```
var myNumbers = [
    [243, 12, 23, 12, 45, 45, 78, 66, 223, 3],
    [34, 2, 1, 553, 23, 4, 66, 23, 4, 55],
    [67, 56, 45, 553, 44, 55, 5, 428, 452, 3],
    [12, 31, 55, 445, 79, 44, 674, 224, 4, 21],
    [4, 2, 3, 52, 13, 51, 44, 1, 67, 5],
    [5, 65, 4, 5, 5, 6, 5, 43, 23, 4424],
    [74, 532, 6, 7, 35, 17, 89, 43, 43, 66],
    [53, 6, 89, 10, 23, 52, 111, 44, 109, 80],
    [67, 6, 53, 537, 2, 168, 16, 2, 1, 8],
    [76, 7, 9, 6, 3, 73, 77, 100, 56, 100]
];

    for(var row=0; row<myNumbers.length; row++) {
         for(var column=0;column<myNumbers[row].length;column++) {
                if(myNumbers[row][column]%2===0) {
                  myNumbers[row][column] = "even";
                } else{ 
                    myNumbers[row][column] = "odd";
                }
            console.log(myNumbers[row][column]);
     }
    }
```

Comment: Wow, I'd never thought of it this way. I am going right away to implement this.

Comment: This is the most straight forward way to perform the replace or by using the splice method noted by @Patrick Evans.  Thanks xrisk

Answer (score 0):

In your inner loop you need to access the values using both indexes (i.e. `myNumbers[row][column]`). As it stands, you are only using the column index and therefore splicing values into the array containing the rows.